# Is there a way to request more than one url in a get method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to java script and I'm having trouble getting my code to work. My get functions need to get from one url, and then get from another and I continuously get header has already been set errors.

```
    app.get('/api/movies/categories/:category',(req,res, next)=>{
        // returns an array of all the movies that fit this year
        //FUTURE IDEA: Check that is has also won an ocscar!
            var inner=0;
            var category = req.params.categories;
            for (i=0; i < csvarray.length; i++){
                if (csvarray[i]['categories'] == category){
                    var prevlength = list2.length;
                    next();
                        if(prevlength != list2.length){
                            list2[o--] = csvarray[i]['categories'];
                        }
                    }

                }

            if(list2.length == 0){
                res.status(404).send(`The Movie category ${req.params} was not found`);  
            }

                res.send(list2);   //if you find the year then send it to the user

    });
    app.get('/api/movies/winners/:winner',(req, next)=>{
        var Trues = req.params.winner;
        if(csvarray[o]['winners'] == Trues){
            list2[o++];
            return;
        }

    });
```

'''
list2 and o are constants so that both get functions could use them. If there is a way to get a function with a req and takes a url that would be perfect, but so far I cannot find any way to do it.

Comment: No, but you can nest your requests, doing everything within the deepest success method... which just expects a single argument result, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Get in the habit of using `return` whenever you send a response. That way it only ever sends one response.

The reason why the error that headers have already been set is showing is because you are calling `res.send()` twice and both of them are being run in the same call to the API handler.

In order to fix it, just use:

`return res.status(404).send(`...

Answer (score 0):

const async = require('async');
    const request = require('request');

```
function httpGet(url, callback) {
  const options = {
    url :  url,
    json : true
  };
  request(options,
    function(err, res, body) {
      callback(err, body);
    }
  );
}
Use promise.all or manually do it by below code
const urls= [
  "http://localhost:3010/alm/build_tool",
  "http://localhost:3010/alm/development_tool",
  "http://localhost:3010/alm/project_architecture"
];

async.map(urls, httpGet, function (err, res){
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is actually making get requests. It looks like an express app responding to get requests, and the problem is the "header has already been set" errors. They likely didn't word the question very precisely.